# Increase in number of divs, while using jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, memory-leaks

I have created three div elements in an HTML page, each of these 3 div elements contain a text box i.e. an input element in it. One div, is made a source while other two are made target. The HTML page has a button name toggle.

The initial connection between source div and one of the target div is created with the help of drag and drop. When toggle is clicked, it will remove the connection between the source and the target, and will create the new connection between source and the other target. Now, when performing analysis using google chrome developer tools over this scenario, the number of div elements keep on increasing by 2 for every toggle.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            jsplumb_demo
        </title>
         <script src="./dist/libs/jquery.js"></script>
         <script src="./src/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./src/jquery.jsPlumb-1.7.6-min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var connection12 = undefined, connection13 = undefined;
            jsPlumb.ready(function() {                       


                var exampleGreyEndpointOptions = {
                    endpoint:"Rectangle",
                    paintStyle:{ width:10, height:10, fillStyle:'#666' },
                    isSource:true,
                    connectorStyle : { strokeStyle:"#666" },
                    isTarget:true,
                    container:$('#container'),
                    connector : "Straight",
                    deleteEndpointsOnDetach: true    
                };



                jsPlumb.makeSource($('div.source'), exampleGreyEndpointOptions);
                jsPlumb.makeTarget($('div.target'),exampleGreyEndpointOptions);
                jsPlumb.makeTarget($('div.target1'),exampleGreyEndpointOptions);

                init = function(connection){    

                };  

                connectionDelete = function(){

                    if(connection12 !== undefined){

                        jsPlumb.detach(connection12);
                        jsPlumb.unmakeTarget($('div.target'));      
                        connection13 = jsPlumb.connect({source : $('#source'), target : $('#target1')},exampleGreyEndpointOptions);
                        connection12 = undefined;
                    }
                    else{

                        jsPlumb.detach(connection13);
                        jsPlumb.unmakeTarget($('div.target'));
                        connection12 = jsPlumb.connect({source : $('#source'), target : $('#target')},exampleGreyEndpointOptions);
                        connection13 = undefined;
                    }
                };      
        });

        jsPlumb.doWhileSuspended(function(){

            jsPlumb.bind("connection", function(connInfo, originalEvent) { 
            init(connInfo.connection);

                    //alert("Source div id = " + connInfo.sourceId + " Target div id = " + connInfo.targetId);
                    var input = "input#" +connInfo.sourceId;
                    var inputval = $(input).val();
                    var output = "input#" +connInfo.targetId;
                    $(output).val(inputval + " from " + connInfo.sourceId);
                    connInfo.targetId ==='target'?connection12 = connInfo : connection13 = connInfo;

        }); 

         jsPlumb.bind("click", function(conn, originalEvent) {
            if (confirm("Delete connection from " + conn.sourceId + " to " + conn.targetId + "?"))
                jsPlumb.detach(conn); 
        }); 

        jsPlumb.bind("connectionDrag", function(connection) {
         //   alert("connection " + connection.id + " is being dragged. suspendedElement is ", connection.suspendedElement, " of type ", connection.suspendedElementType);
        });     

        jsPlumb.bind("connectionDragStop", function(connection) {
           // alert("connection " + connection.id + " was dragged");
        });

        jsPlumb.bind("connectionMoved", function(params) {
            //alert("connection " + params.connection.id + " was moved");
        });

        });
        </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        <div  class="source" id="source" style="position: absolute;left: 200px" > 

            <input/>    

        </div>
        <div  class="target" id="target" style="position: absolute;left: 600px" >

            <input />   

        </div>

        <div  class="target1" id="target1" style="position: absolute;left: 600px; top:200px" > 

            <input />   

        </div>
        </div>
        <button name="delete" type="button" onclick="connectionDelete()">Toggle</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit :-

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Rahil_Khera/L6nks8kp/4/)

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: okay, here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Rahil_Khera/L6nks8kp/3/

Comment: there is a error in console, which is pointing to `jsplumb` plugin, are u missing something ?

Comment: Nope I just checked it again, no errors.

cdn for jquery ui :- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js

cdn for jsplumb :- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsPlumb/1.4.1/jquery.jsPlumb-1.4.1-all-min.js

Comment: hit the toggle button, you will know there is a error in console `Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined`

Comment: Oh, I got it. You have to first create the connection by drag and drop and then hit the toggle button. Else it will not work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Rahil_Khera/L6nks8kp/4/ try this one, this will not require creation of any connections, just hit toggle button.