# Accessing memory address of an html DOM element

Tags: html, dom, memory, memory-address

Every html element present on the an html page consumes some form of memory. So is there any method to fetch the memory address where an HTML element is stored.  As, the DOM is stored in local memory, there should be some memory map or some attribute which shows the value of memory address where it is stored.

Actually want to delete the html element on the basis of memory address as element is available in the memory, since it can be seen in memory heap shot but not in the heap.

[Increase in number of divs, while using jsPlumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802872/increase-in-number-of-divs-while-using-jsplumb)

A fiddle is given in above link. Perform following steps to understand the problem:

1. Take a heap snap shot by using google chrome developer tool.
2. Press Toggle Button.
3. Take another heap snap shot by using google chrome developer tool.
4. Check the html div elements in both the snapshot.

Note :- When connection is removed the endpoints related to it should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean "Using JavaScript from within a webpage": No.

Access to memory is completely abstracted in JavaScript.

If you want to remove an HTML element from memory then remove it from the DOM, delete all references to it (or let them fall out of scope) and then let garbage collection handle it.

Comment: Yes using java script or jQuery. I am using jsPlumb for connection between the elements, but once I remove the connection between two elements, the divs are removed from the DOM and also there are no more references, but still they appear in memory, i.e. when memory heap shot is taken.  


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802872/increase-in-number-of-divs-while-using-jsplumb

Check above link. It also contains a fiddle. 

Take heap snapshot
Click on toggle
Take heap snapshot
and compare html div elements. you will get the problem am asking.